# Wrong jumper cable intallation

Tags: starting, chevrolet, diesel, captiva

I have a chevrolet captiva 2010 diesel model. The mechanic installed the jumper cables backward. My suv doesn't start anymore.(it doesn't crank) What could be the problem? What should I check? Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! If the mechanic installed the cables backwards, tell him to fix it *at his expense*. What may be wrong  really depends on the symptoms of "won't start". Does it turn over but not sound like it's doing anything (crank no start) or not cranking at all? Give us a little more information as to what's going on.

Comment: do you mean jumper cables ( as in jump start from another car ) or battery cables?  If you were jumping it presumably you had a bad battery to begin with, did you take care of that?

Comment: There may be a *fusible link* blown that prevents power getting to the starter solenoid.  Does everything else work (headlights, radio, instrument cluster, etc) ?  Fusible links can carry very high currents, but are subtle in that they appear like just a normal piece of wire.

Answer (score 0):

@Paulster2 is right in that more information would be helpful, but first of all, the problem is that you have a terrible mechanic. *No* proper mechanic should get the connections wrong for jumping a cap.

That aside, wiring your battery wrong is likely to kill the battery (essentially, you've shorted the battery, and it likely hydrolyzed the water in the battery). Simplest check is to swap the battery, or try jumping *correctly* from another vehicle. If it still doesn't start, you may have a bigger problem.

Comment: Check for a main fuse. If connected backwards it probably blew the fuse.

Comment: I don't think there's usually a fuse to protect the battery from overcurrent. It would have to be insanely large (ex. 200A+) to handle cranking. If he shorted the battery with jumper cables, it would have also bypassed any "main" fuses.

Comment: Honda had them for years, so I would at least give it a look. It doesn't protect the battery, just the components in the car from damage.

Comment: There are two 50 amp fuses in the under hood fuse box. Check those first. If they are ok, check the RAP relay in the fuse box inside the vehicle, relay 22. RAP stands for "retained accessory power". You can temporarily swap it with the defrost relay to see if it will start, but get the correct one if it works, and put the defrost relay back in their original position. Happy hunting!!

Answer (score 0):

cars/trucks have a main fuse, if you trace the positive cable it will lead to the fuse box. you will probably see it going into two 50amp fuses or a 100amp fuse. if the fuse is not blown, then the wire going to it probably is... a simple volt meter continuity(beeping thing) test between positive battery terminal and the fuses will reveal where the wire is broken.